# Primary key field is not getting validated for uniqueness in cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I am working on cakephp framework,where mysql is back end.I am developing form to enter product details,where product_id is to be added manually.I have written the validation rules for product_id field.It works for other validation rules i.e. for not empty, numeric.But not working for unique validation rule.Here is my validation code in the model:

```
var $validate= array(product_id=>
                                  'numeric'=> array('rule'=>'numeric',
                  'on'=>'create',
                  'message'=>'Please enter only numbers'),
                                  'isUnique' => array('rule' => 'isUnique',
                        message' => 'This product_id already exist'),

                 'notEmpty'=> array('rule' => 'notEmpty',
                        message' => 'Please enter the product id')),

            'product_name' => array('notEmpty'=> array(
                                    'rule' => 'notEmpty',
                                    'message' => 'Please enter the product name')));
```

I couldn't able to point out the error location.

Comment: It looks like your array format is completely screwed up. Try formatting it a bit and then count your opening and closing parentheses.

Comment: In addition to my post, any true primary key is already unique, and be auto-incremented - so this should not be  necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shouldn't it be:

```
var $validate= array('product_id'=> array('rule'=>'numeric',
                    'on'=>'create',
                     //etc
```

Else you are attempting to validate a field called `numeric`?

Also, whilst I don't know how your app functions, using `product_id` sounds like it should relate to another record, in the `products` table - which would be automatically dealt with with Cake i.e. in a select.

If you are entering a unique code (such as an internal Reference number), consider renaming the field to something less-Cake-like to prevent any issues that may arise, or confusion with another Cake developer.

Comment: :Thanks, You are right. That was copy, paste mistake. I miss product_id while copying. Still uniqueness is not validating?

Comment: Try it on another field, see if that works. My guess is still that you're trying to validate `isUnique` on something that should already be unique by nature, so perhaps Cake is ignoring it. What's the datatype?

Comment: Datatype is integer, i tried removing isUnique validation rule, then previous record is getting override.