# Can we validate the primary key field for uniqueness in cakephp validation?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I am doing form validation using cakephp validation method. My form has product_id field which is primary key in database.I am validating my product_id field for uniqueness but it is not getting validate. I could not able to find the root cause. what might be the case?

Thanks 
Pushpa

Comment: Please submit your model code as well. Why do you would like to do this on your PK? Normally your either insert a new record with automatically generated unique PK, or you edit one, where the PK isn't changed and is already unique.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Primary key field is not getting validated for uniqueness in cakephp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6562842/primary-key-field-is-not-getting-validated-for-uniqueness-in-cakephp)

Comment: Either you have a wrong approach or the database structure is messed up. You should never set IDs of new records manually and certainly not by data coming from forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is where it specifies the details of `isUnique` model validation:

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1166/isUnique

If you're doing it per the instructions, it should work just fine.  Beyond that, there's nothing we can do to help.

Answer (score 0):

primaries should be per definition unique and therefore checking for this is superfluous.
the framework provides you with unique keys both for AIIDs and UUIDs

in your case it seems this is actually a foreign_key is this relation.
so your question was wrongly stated.
you want to check on a simple isUnique for a single row.

isUnique is the validation rule you are looking for.
http://book.cakephp.org/view/1166/isUnique